# Transparent BG MOV not working in Premiere

Tags: animation

I have a blender file that someone sent me with text and streaking graphics, similar to the opening credits of Superman The Movie.  When I export this animation as an MOV animation video (RLE codec; all the appropriate boxes are checked for transparent alpha), the videos play in standalone video player, but not in Premiere.  If I attempt to export to PNG, I get only the transparent background, not the text.  In Premiere, the only way to see the video is if I disregard or invert the alpha channel, which defeats the purpose since it removes the transparency.  I know it's not a Premiere issue because I have other transparent MOV files (that I did not create) which work when imported.  Any help?

Comment: A: This is not a forum for Premiere. B: Why are you encoding as video and not as image sequence in a format that supports proper alpha (EXR, or Tiff, for example) and bring that into premiere? C: Are you using RGBA in the output settings? D: What render engine are you using? E: If you are using cycles is Film Transparent enabled? F: Is "use alpha" enabled in the compositor?  G: is the output for alpha connected to the alpha socket of the output node? H: Is your text luminous (as in no diffuse shader but just emission? Please clarify...

Comment: A. Which is why I’m not asking a question about a Premiere function but rather one about a Blender function to facilitate Premiere compatibility. B. As I indicated, I’ve attempted to export to an image sequence, but all I get are transparent files.  I thought PNG was adequate for this, but am willing to try TIFF instead.  C. Yes.  D. Blender Render, but I’ll use any that will work.  E. Yes, when I’ve tried Cycles, I’ve had transparency enabled.  F. Yes.  As for G and H, I have no clue.  TOTAL Blender noob here.

Comment: I’ve now tried exporting a TIFF image sequence.  Same results.  Only transparent photos, no animation.  The strange thing is, I can see the TIFF’s rendering in Blender WITH the animation.  I have no idea why it’s not present in the finished images.